# how do I get my code to output the number of vowels and characters?

Tags: linux

I cannot figure out why this code is not printing all of the characters and vowels.. I have tried several different things, but I keep getting the same results.

```
#! /bim/bash
myString= cat sampletext.txt
line= wc -l < sampletext.txt
echo 
cnt=0
a=0
e=0
i=0
o=0
u=0
while (( i++ < ${#myString} )); do
    char=$(expr substr "$myString" $i 1)
    if ["$char" == "a" ]; then
        ((a++))
    elif [ "$char" == "e" ]; then
        ((e++))
    elif ["$char" == "i" ]; then
        ((i++))
    elif ["$char" == "o" ]; then
        ((o++))
    elif [ "$char" == "u" ]; then
        ((u++))
    fi
done
((vowels=a+e+i+o+u))
((cnt=cnt=line))
echo "The total number of characters is $cnt with $vowels vowels."
echo "The breakdown of vowels (a,e,i,o,u) is $a a's, $e e's, $i i's, $o o's, $u u's"
```

My output(very wrong):

```
The total number of characters is 0 with 1 vowels.
The breakdown of vowels (a,e,i,o,u) is 0 a's, 0 e's, 1 i's, 0 o's, 0 u's
```

The correct output should be:

```
The total number of characters is 12 with 5 vowels. 
The breakdown of vowels (a,e,i,o,u) is 0 a's, 1 e's, 2 i's, 1 o's and 1 u's
```

Comment: Why the `vi` and `vim` tags?

Comment: `((cnt=cnt=line))` ??  I suppose you meant `((cnt=cnt+line))`?

Comment: Not sure if you're more interested in why your current code is wrong or a working solution, but a good way to count vowels is to delete everything other than a vowel (with `tr`) and pipe the result to `wc -c`.  Eg `vowel_count=$(tr -dc '[aeiouAEIOU]' < input | wc -c)`

Comment: @WilliamPursell But they also want the breakdown by individual vowel.

Comment: FYI, bash has a built-in substring operator, you don't need to use `expr`.

Comment: Paste your code into shellcheck.net. You'll find that there's a problem with most of your `if` statements. `["$char"` needs a space after `[`

Comment: `myString= cat sampletext.txt` is missing the backticks or `$()` around `cat sampletext.txt`. The next line has the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed version

```bash
#!/bin/bash
myString=$(cat sampletext.txt)
 
counter=0
a=0
e=0
i=0
o=0
u=0

while (( counter++ < ${#myString} )); do
    char=$(expr substr "$myString" $counter 1)

    if [ "$char" == "a" ]; then
        ((a++))
    elif [ "$char" == "e" ]; then
        ((e++))
    elif [ "$char" == "i" ]; then
        ((i++))
    elif [ "$char" == "o" ]; then
        ((o++))
    elif [ "$char" == "u" ]; then
        ((u++))
    fi
done

((vowels=a+e+i+o+u))
echo "The total number of characters is $counter with $vowels vowels."
echo "The breakdown of vowels (a,e,i,o,u) is $a a's, $e e's, $i i's, $o o's, $u u's"
```

Diff view

```
-#! /bim/bash
-myString= cat sampletext.txt
-line= wc -l < sampletext.txt
-echo 
-cnt=0
+#!/bin/bash
+myString=$(cat sampletext.txt)
+ 
+counter=0
 a=0
 e=0
 i=0
 o=0
 u=0
-while (( i++ < ${#myString} )); do
-    char=$(expr substr "$myString" $i 1)
-    if ["$char" == "a" ]; then
-        ((a++))
-    elif [ "$char" == "e" ]; then
-        ((e++))
-    elif ["$char" == "i" ]; then
-        ((i++))
-    elif ["$char" == "o" ]; then
-        ((o++))
-    elif ["$char" == "u" ]; then
-        ((u++))
+
+while (( counter++ < ${#myString} )); do
+    char=$(expr substr "$myString" $counter 1)
+
+       if [ "$char" == "a" ]; then
+               ((a++))
+       elif [ "$char" == "e" ]; then
+               ((e++))
+    elif [ "$char" == "i" ]; then
+               ((i++))
+    elif [ "$char" == "o" ]; then
+               ((o++))
+     elif [ "$char" == "u" ]; then
+               ((u++))
     fi
 done
+
 ((vowels=a+e+i+o+u))
-((cnt=cnt=line))
-echo "The total number of characters is $cnt with $vowels vowels."
+echo "The total number of characters is $counter with $vowels vowels."
 echo "The breakdown of vowels (a,e,i,o,u) is $a a's, $e e's, $i i's, $o o's, $u u's"
```

You did the following wrong:

- The shebang was set to `#! /bim/bash` instead of `#!/bin/bash`
- I am not sure whether it works or not but if you assign variables to a command output you should put the command within `$()`
- The while loop used `i` as its condition but `i` is a var for the vowels. You must use `cnt` instead
- `substr` must also use `cnt` instead of `i`

Comment: Both `#! /bim/bash` and `#!/bin/bash` are specifically allowed. See [Is space allowed between #! and /bin/bash in shebang?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/276751/197080)

Comment: Ok I accept the space(s) but /bi`m`/bash?

Comment: Chuckling -- fat fingers...